# Convert percentage to range

Tags: logarithms

I have the following function to convert this function to percentage. The range of $y$ is $-120$ to $0$, so $-120 = 0\%$ and $0 = 100\%$.

$$percentage = 10^{(y + 160) / 80}$$

How do I go the other way by converting a percentage to the range $-120$ to $0$?

This doesn't quite work

$$y = 80 * log_{10}(percentage) - 160$$

Code to convert range $(-120, 0)$ to percentage

```
if (y > -120) {
    n = Math.pow(10, ((y + 160) / 80));
    if (n > 100) {
        n = 100;
    }
    if (n < 0) {
        n = 0;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

BT

Comment: You really don't want this to be linear??

Comment: Sorry, yes I do

Comment: IOW, $\mathrm{percentage} = \frac{5}{6}y+100$ wouldn't work?

Comment: Your problem is that you can't take the log of $0$, but $0$ is a valid percentage.

Comment: Or, the problem is that your formula does not convert $-120$ correctly.

Comment: Thanks Randal, edge cases can be handled in software

Comment: when you plug 1% into the second equation I get -160, not what I want

Comment: Right:  my answer below shows what's going on.

Comment: maybe this is more appropriate to ask on code review, another forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first stated formula is incorrect:  it does not do what you claim it does.

With $y=-120$, your formula gives
$$
\mathrm{percentage} = 10^{0.5} =\sqrt{10} \neq 0.
$$ 
So, your formula does NOT convert $-120$ to $0\%$.  Instead, it converts it to roughly $3.16\%$.  (It does, however, convert $y=0$ to $100\%$, but that's not good enough here.)

Anyway, because this part was wrong, this is why your log formula also fails.

If you just need any way at all to convert these, use something linear.  So,
$$
\mathrm{percentage} =\frac{5}{6}y+100
$$
in one direction and
$$
y=\frac{6}{5}(\mathrm{percentage}-100)
$$
in the other.

Comment: Thanks Randall, if you have the time could you explain how you derived the 5/6 and the inverse 6/5, Thanks once again :)

Comment: You want pairs $(-120,0)$ and $(0,100)$, so figure out the slope and connect the dots.

Comment: Thanks, make sense, easy when you know how, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue which is that your mapping is not a bijection between $[-120, 0]$ and $[0, 100]$. So you cannot invert it to convert back our percentage into your initial value.